# Does GNU FORTH have an editor?

Tags: forth, gforth

Chapter 3 of [Starting FORTH](http://www.forth.com/starting-forth/) says,

> Now that you've made a block "current", you can list it by simply typing the word `L`. Unlike `LIST`, `L` does not want to be proceeded by a block number; instead it lists the current block.

When I run `180 LIST`, I get

```
Screen 180 not modified     
0                                                                 
...                                                             
15                                                                 
 ok
```

But when I run `L`, I get an error

```
:30: Undefined word
>>>L<<<
Backtrace:
$7F0876E99A68 throw 
$7F0876EAFDE0 no.extensions 
$7F0876E99D28 interpreter-notfound1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, gForth supports an internal (BLOCK) editor. Start gforth

1. type: `use blocked.fb` (a demo page)
2. type: `1 load`
3. type `editor`
4. `words` will show the editor words,

   ```
   s b n bx nx qx dl il f y r d i t 'par 'line 'rest c a m  ok
   ```
5. type `0 l` to list screen 0 which describes the editor,

   ```
   Screen 0 not modified     
    0 \\ some comments on this simple editor                 29aug95py
    1 m marks current position        a goes to marked position       
    2 c moves cursor by n chars       t goes to line n and inserts    
    3 i inserts                       d deletes marked area           
    4 r replaces marked area          f search and mark               
    5 il insert a line                dl delete a line                
    6 qx gives a quick index          nx gives next index             
    7 bx gives previous index                                         
    8 n goes to next screen           b goes to previous screen       
    9 l goes to screen n              v goes to current screen        
   10 s searches until screen n       y yank deleted string           
   11                                                                 
   12 Syntax and implementation style a la PolyFORTH                  
   13 If you don't like it, write a block editor mode for Emacs!      
   14                                                                 
   15                                                                 
    ok
   ```

## Creating your own block file

To create your own new block file `myblocks.fb`

1. type: `use blocked.fb`
2. type: `1 load`
3. type `editor`

Then

1. type `use myblocks.fb`
2. `1 load` will show BLOCK #1 (lines 0 till 15. 16 Lines of 64 characters each)
3. `1 t` will highlight line 1
4. Type `i this is text` to [i]nsert into line 1
5. After the current BLOCK is edited type `flush` in order to write BLOCK #1 to the file `myblocks.fb`

For more information see, [gForth Blocks](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Blocks.html)

Comment: some of your shortcuts, didn't work in gForth, I confirmed that this edit works though. Welcome to the site, great contribution.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out these are "Editor Commands" the book says,

> **For Those Whose EDITOR Doesn't Follow These Rules**
>
> The FORTH-79 Standard does not specify editor commands. Your system may use a different editor; if so, check your systems documentation

I don't believe gforth supports an internal editor at all. So `L`, `T`, `I`, `P`, `F`, `E`, `D`, `R` are all presumably unsupported.

Comment: Nope, no internail editor in gforth. It assumes you run emacs.

Comment: @vonbrand I guess it doesn't any more or we just overlooked the feature see the chosen answer now

Answer (score 1):

gforth is well integrated with emacs. In my xemacs here, by default any file called *.fs is considered FORTH source. "C-h m", as usual, gives the available commands.

Answer (score 0):

No, GNU Forth doesn't have an internal editor; I use Vim :)

Comment: See the chosen answer